# Entity Framework Code First Doesn't Generate Database

Tags: entity-framework-4

I created a db Context class and added a connection string in my web.config file as instructed in Scott Guthrie's [Code First Development with Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx).  I am running it from a test method.  I received several database errors running the tests, but when I finally cleaned up the classes so the test succeeded, I still had no database in the App_data folder.

I added Database.CreateIfNotExists() to the dbContext constructor, but still no sdf file.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 23):

For the database to be automatically created, the connection string name has to be named exactly as the DbContext subclass name (with namespace).

Eg. Say your DB class is like this:

```csharp
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class FooDb : DbContext
    {    
        public DbSet<XXX> ABC{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your connection string should look like so:

```xml
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyNamespace.FooDb" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyNamespace.FooDb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Namespace or not, does't matter for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check SQL Server Management Studio -> .\sqlexpress

That's where CF has been putting all my databases when I don't specify a connection string.

Comment: True, without connection string the database is created in web server working directory.

Answer (score 2):

See here for auto-creating the .sdf with EF 4.1 and the SQL CE NuGet package (or a new MVC 3 project apparently):

http://www.goatly.net/2011/6/27/entity-framework-code-first-the-path-is-not-valid-check-the-directory-for-the-database.aspx

**Long story short:** Create an empty App_Data folder - the sdf is auto created, but only if the folder it goes in is present.

Comment: -1's without explanation hurt the community, especially if they invalidate a reasonable answer.  This worked for me, and it took a long time to figure out.  I came back to a post that had not provided the answer, and provided what I had found.  So why the minus?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dbcontext using correct connection string
Some thing similar like this

```
public class DBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DBContext ()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
}
```

And in web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=....;Connection Timeout=300;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```