# Entity Framework Code First App_Data is empty and i cant find it anywhere

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I am working in Visual Studio 2012 professional and I made some classes and used the EF to generate the dataBase. The DB works fine but the App_Data is empty. I wanna know if i can make anything to the files show up. Or where can I find the DataBase in some place else? I really need to find the DataBase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your solution folder and you will see the generated database.

Check same post here : [Entity Framework Code First Doesn't Generate Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877784/entity-framework-code-first-doesnt-generate-database)

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately i couldnt make it work. And i went to the folder and the mdf file cannot be open by Visual Studio. It only opens by DaemonTools

Comment: Dude...
I tried your solution and added this conectionString....
 <add name="BreakAwayContext"
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BreakAway.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>.........
The .mdf file shows up but now i have problem with Login access and i cant open it

Answer (score 1):

By default, Code First has created the database on localhost\SQLEXPRESS using the fully qualified name of your context class for the database name.

Comment: I am not being able to acces this on the browser .

Comment: you must use SQL Studio Management or Server Explorer in VS to access the database

Comment: I tried the server explorer...
I clicked on Add a conection...
I put Server Name = test....
I atached a database file and chose the MDF file that i want....
but it didnt work, it says that the server was not found or wasnt acessible....
i will download SQL studio management and see if it works

Comment: try to use .\SQLEXPRESS or [ComputerName]\SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 1):

If EntityFramework couldn't find a connection string in the App.config or Web.config, it creates the database in the current user's profile folder. Go to your user's profile folder in order to see the database files.

Comment: that could have been a comment, nothing much like an answer

Comment: @KrunalPatil It seems an answer for me, since the OP is not finding the DB.

Comment: @falsarella, yeah after the answer was given, there's nothing much to answer but can be a comment, that's what I think. Rest its upto you. Thank you, for your comment.