# Running update-database results in the error: "A file activation error occurred"

Tags: database, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

Basically I've created a class library project containing a data access repository for other projects to use.
I've added the EF6 package and enabled migrations.
My connection string in app.config looks the following:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Pbn" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Pbn.mdf;Initial Catalog=LM.DataAccess;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

(The project name is LM.DataAccess).

When I run the update-database command I get the following error:

> A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\Pbn.mdf'
>   may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry
>   the operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could
>   not be created. Check related errors.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882560/entity-framework-code-first-update-database-fails-on-create-database

Answer (score 7):

This is the problem:

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Pbn.mdf
```

That's being interpreted as \Pbn.mdf, and it doesn't exist. This is because you aren't setting the |DataDirectory| value, so it's blank. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented) on how to set it.

Comment: I see. However where do I change the dataDirectory?
I mean unlike a web project there aren't a global.asax file(where I usually would put this) in my class library.

Comment: True, but there is a Program.cs in console and WinForm apps. WPF has App.xaml.cs, so there's something for everyone!

Comment: Yes but mine is a classs library which doesn't have neither. I tried adding Program.cs, like a console app would have but it didn't get fired.
By the way - sorry for my delayed answers but I'm trying everything you're saying :)

Comment: You need to a) set it whatever project uses your library b) set it in your library sometime before the first time you use the connection string c) don't use |DataDirectory|! Use the proper path!